# Python Selenium : finding an element and clicking a button based on Text

Tags: python, selenium

Basically, I am trying to create a bot that can find an element on a page with a given raw_input text, finding the button, and clicking it. The purpose of this is to click on links (buttons) that may not be on the web page yet, but will appear after the site refreshes. Because of this, I cannot find elements by XPATH, because the XPATH will be unknown until the second the link becomes available. So, my question is: is there a way for Selenium to find a button based on text and click it? Here is some of my code:

```
key1 = raw_input('Enter the first keyword: ')
key2 = raw_input('Enter the second keyword: ')
key3 = raw_input('Enter the third keyword: ')
```

...

```
elem1 =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), key1)]")
    if elem1.is_displayed():
        elem1.click()
    else:
        print "Cannot find element to click. Retrying..."
        driver.refresh()
```

I need the program to find the text based on the keywords, and then click the button / link with these keywords in it. Is this possible? or only possible with XPATHs? The example code i gave with giving an elem has not been working.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first of all, the only one of selecting an element by text is sadly xpath, but do not worry, there is a workaround you could use waits

```
#Libraries (those comes with selenium, you don't have to install anything)
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#Way
elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(), 
{})]'.format(key1))
)
elem1.click()
```

this will make it wait for the element to be clickable if the element is not clickable after 10 seconds it will raise an error if it gets clickable before that time it will return the element and break the wait automatically.